# javamail: why does getDisposition cause an 'Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE' error?

Tags: jakarta-mail, attachment

connection type: IMAPS

When I call 'getDisposition' on an email such that the attachment bound to the mail is an EML file, javamail throws an 'Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE' exception.

I'm unclear why this happens. Ideas, anybody?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JAVAMAIL API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html).

It is a "bad" server issue.

```
try {
    msg.getContentType(); // or getDisposition or similar
} catch (Exception e) {
    errorMsg = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage)msg);
}
    ...
someProcessing(errorMsg);
```